# How to sort treemap with negative values as key

Tags: java, sorting, key-value, treemap

I have a Map which contains **+ve** and **-ve** values as key

```
Map<String,Integer> dr=new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
```

So i am putting "-1" when putting the negative values. SInce this is a treemap so the values are stored in sorted manner .After i put the values and print the treemap using this function

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : dr.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Output

```
-1: 4
-2: 3
-3: 5
0: 1
1: 2
2: 5
3: 6
```

Ideally this should be the output, right?

```
-3: 5
-2: 3
-1: 4
0: 1
1: 2
2: 5
3: 6
```

How can I achieve this output?

Comment: TreeMap sorts using the key. In this case, your key should be Integer, Use `Map<Integer, Integer>` insead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TreeMap sorts using the key. In this case, your key should be Integer, Use Map instead

```
Map<Integer,Integer> dr=new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

and baam , the answer comes. :)